# EF Code First: Adding child entities to a new entity

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm currently trying to migrate our model from edmx to Code First, but having some trouble seeding the database.

I have these (simplified) entities:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public EntityBase()
    {
        this.OfficeEntities = new HashSet<OfficeEntity>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OfficeEntity> OfficeEntities { get; set; }
}

public class Office : EntityBase
{
    public Office()
    {
        this.EntityCollection = new HashSet<OfficeEntity>();
    }

    public ICollection<OfficeEntity> EntityCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : EntityBase
{
    // misc properties not in use by the associatio in this example
}

public class OfficeEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OfficeEntityPositions { get; set; }
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public int EntityBaseId { get; set; }

    public Office Office { get; set; }
    public EntityBase Entity { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using these entities when trying to seed the database:

```
var office = new Office();
var employees = GenerateEmployees(); // A method that simply creates a list of new employee objects
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    office.EntityCollection.Add(new OfficeEntity {Entity = employee, OfficeEntityPositions = 1});
}

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This will only add new office entity to the database, everything else is left out (Employees and OfficeEntitites). Everything looks nice in the database schema when it comes to FK relationships.

This seems to be occurring elsewhere in my db seeding where I create new entities and add new child objects to them too where only the parent is added :S

Any idea about how to troubleshoot this?